# Display screenshots on test failure in azure devops pipeline

Tags: testing, azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-pipelines, testcafe

I would like to display a screenshot when a testcafe test is failed in azure pipeline, I can't use anything from marketplace, so it needs to be with copy files task (as recommended by my colleague).
How should I do that?

[image: This is a screenshot of the copy file task in the task group]

[image: And here is the screenshot for my powershell script]

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot show the screenshot in the pipeline, as a workaround, we could show the report.xml content in the pipeline via [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md).

Since the logging command need use local file, we need [configure self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) and copy the report.xml file to another path, then show the report.xml content in the pipeline.

Add the task `power shell` after the task `copy file` and enter the below script

```
Copy-Item -Path $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\report.html -Destination {local folder path} –Recurse


Write-Host "##vso[task.addattachment type=Distributedtask.Core.Summary;name=testcafeFailLog;]{local folder path}\report.html"
```

Result:

I did a simple test, you could check it

[image]